# Пакет Reflect не могу заполнить структуру для данных

Tags: golang

передаю структуру как интерфейс хочу  заполнить ее значениями. имена полей известны. Как можно это сделать? Нашел что это делается при помощи пакета reflect. Делал как в описании 
    `v := reflect.ValueOf(data).Elem()` 
    `v.FieldByName("UserName").SetString("Greg")`
ожидаю что после выполнения этих методов в структуре data в поле UserName будет лежать строка Greg.
получаю ошибку
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value[recovered]
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value

Comment: Покажите весь код, желательно на https://play.golang.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажите ваш код. Обычно, всё работает так:

```
type User struct {
    Name string
}

func setName(u interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(u)
    v.Elem().FieldByName("Name").SetString("Greg")
}

func main() {
    u := &User{}
    setName(u)
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5voMPz27fk.